# Not able to use require.undef in dojo 1.9

Tags: dojo, require, amd

I'm not able to access to the require method 'undef', it's undefined in my require object.

The dojo version I'm using is 1.9

I thought that with the follow flag should be able to use it, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something (plus other properties of the build of course):

```
var dojoConfig = {
    hasCache: {
        "dojo-undef-api": 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work if you define it via `dojoConfig.has` rather than `dojoConfig.hasCache`.  Dojo reads `hasCache` from its own default configuration, but it reads the `has` property from user configuration (e.g. `dojoConfig`).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my dojo version has no references to the 'dojo-undef-api' inside its layer. But thanks Ken Franqueiro for the trick in the dojoConfig, I'll have it in mind next time as well.

Comment: By default, builds set `dojo-undef-api` to `0` in `staticHasFeatures`.  You can override this in your own build profile's `staticHasFeatures` (assuming you have control of the build you're using).